# HTML/JSP visual design mode

Tags: html, jsp, netbeans

I'm wondering if the sun netbeans IDE can support visual design editor for html or jsp (no problem for JSF) or not?

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588068/html-jsp-visual-design-editor/1588099#1588099 Please do not do this sort of thing on stack overflow. It will usually result in your question(s) being closed and left unanswered.

Comment: Tnay, you say in 1588068 that it is a duplicate of this one. Which is the chicken and which is the egg. Only one should be marked as a duplicate, or neither will get answered.

Comment: Well, what comes first the chicken or the egg? In either case id call this one the egg. :-p
(this is the original)

Answer (score 1):

There is no visual designer as such for html/jsp. There was [proposal](http://wiki.netbeans.org/WebPageDesigner) made a long time back, but never got implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You mean an editing mode like Dreamweaver's?  No it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

*Here is the answer I posted on the other version of your question (the one which got deleted):*

Yes, Building out Visual JSF inside of an IDE like netbeans may be what you are referring to.

Here is a good tutorial from Netbeans.

> This tutorial gives you a whirlwind tour of Visual Web JSF
>   application development in NetBeans
>   IDE 6.5. The tutorial shows you how to
>   use Visual Web JSF Application
>   functionality and JavaServer Faces 1.2
>   (Woodstock) components to perform the
>   typical phases of web application
>   development.
>
> The tutorial is designed so that you do not need to go through it in
>   any particular order. You might want
>   to skim over it quickly and then
>   return to each section as time allows.

Comment: -1 as (s)he specifically says "html or jsp (no problem for JSF)"

Comment: I had answered his other duplicate question first, in which the way it was phrased made it seem as if he was looking for a way to do JSF editing.

Comment: Tnay, see my comment on the OP's question.

Comment: @tnay cannot retract my downvote, upvoted your comment to compensate... :-)