# HTML / JSP Visual Design Editor

Tags: html, jsp, netbeans

Is there a graphical design tool for html/jsp pages like jsf pages (like the aspx .net environment)?

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587652/html-jsp-visual-design-mode

Please do not do this sort of thing on stack overflow. It will usually result in your question(s) being closed and left unanswered.

Comment: Tnay, you say in 1587652 that it is a duplicate of this one. Which is the chicken and which is the egg. Only one should be marked as a duplicate, or neither will get answered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Building out Visual JSF inside of an IDE like netbeans may be what you are referring to.

[Here is a good tutorial from Netbeans.](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/intro.html)

> This tutorial gives you a whirlwind
>   tour of Visual Web JSF application
>   development in NetBeans IDE 6.5. The
>   tutorial shows you how to use Visual
>   Web JSF Application functionality and
>   JavaServer Faces 1.2 (Woodstock)
>   components to perform the typical
>   phases of web application development.
>
> The tutorial is designed so that you
>   do not need to go through it in any
>   particular order. You might want to
>   skim over it quickly and then return
>   to each section as time allows.